# Incoming Voice Webhook is getting called twice for the same call

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api

Trying to understand why the incoming voice call webhook is getting called twice.

The phone numbers's voice webhook url is set up to point to my backend and the api endpoint rejects the call right away as follows.

```
const voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse();
voiceResponse.reject({ reason: 'busy' });
res.type('text/xml');
res.end(voiceResponse.toString());
```

However, the same call with a different CallSid is pinging the webhook again after a couple of seconds.

Comment: That's odd. There's nothing wrong with that TwiML response. I recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and supplying Call SIDs for occurrences where this happened.

Comment: Will do, thanks @philnash

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this issue? I have the same thing happening.